How to combine two triggers that updates one table in psql?
I don't actually know if triggers are the best way to go about this, but essentially I'm trying to construct a customer order management system that includes a 'deposit' of sorts along with each order.
I want to keep track of the total number of each SKU a customer orders, and the total number of returns of the SKU. These orders are tracked in the Orders (and OrderDetails) table, and returns in the DepositReturns (and DepositReturnsDetail) table, and their total ordered vs total due is tracked in a CustomerDepositBalance table
I tried creating a trigger trigger_update_deposit_balance_order() and trigger_update_deposit_balance_return() it does update the CustomerDepositBalance, but only if I have one of them. The second trigger just doesn't run (i.e., if I put the orders trigger first then the returns trigger, totalOrdered updates but the totalReturns won't update).
Here's my code for each trigger. They have the same logic since Orders and Returns are pretty much structured the same.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_deposit_balance_order()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  order_customerID INT;
  customer_deposit_balance_id INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT customerID INTO order_customerID FROM Orders WHERE orderID = NEW.orderID;
  SELECT customerDepositBalanceID INTO customer_deposit_balance_id
  FROM CustomerDepositBalance
  WHERE customerID = order_customerID AND productID = NEW.productID;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO CustomerDepositBalance (customerID, productID, totalOrdered)
    VALUES (order_customerID, NEW.productID, NEW.quantity);
  ELSE
    UPDATE CustomerDepositBalance
    SET totalOrdered = totalOrdered + NEW.quantity
    WHERE customerDepositBalanceID = customer_deposit_balance_id;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_deposit_balance_order
AFTER INSERT ON OrderDetails
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_deposit_balance_order();



--- For updating returns
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_deposit_balance_return()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  depositReturn_customerID INT;
  customer_deposit_balance_id INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT customerID INTO depositReturn_customerID FROM DepositReturns WHERE depositReturnID = NEW.depositReturnID;
  SELECT customerDepositBalanceID INTO customer_deposit_balance_id
  FROM CustomerDepositBalance
  WHERE customerID = depositReturn_customerID AND productID = NEW.productID;

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO CustomerDepositBalance (customerID, productID, totalReturned)
    VALUES (depositReturn_customerID, NEW.productID, NEW.quantity);
  ELSE
    UPDATE CustomerDepositBalance
    SET totalReturned = totalReturned + NEW.quantity
    WHERE customerDepositBalanceID = customer_deposit_balance_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_deposit_balance_return
AFTER INSERT ON DepositReturnDetails
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_deposit_balance_return();

And just in case it's relevant, I've added the customerDepositBalance here
CREATE TABLE CustomerDepositBalance (
  customerDepositBalanceID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  customerID INT,
  productID INT,
  totalOrdered INT,  
  totalReturned INT,  
  PRIMARY KEY (customerDepositBalanceID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_customerID FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customers(customerID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_productID FOREIGN KEY (productID) REFERENCES Products(productID)
);

I'm entirely new to sql; I have no idea what I'm doing. I tried to combine the two triggers into one big one by using IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'OrderDetails' THEN to identify which column to update based on the table, but that didn't work. The code ran but the CustomerDepositBalance was completely empty after my inserts.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_deposit_balance()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  customerID INT;
  customer_deposit_balance_id INT;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Trigger executed for %', TG_TABLE_NAME;

  IF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'OrderDetails' THEN
    SELECT customerID INTO customerID FROM Orders WHERE orderID = NEW.orderID;

    SELECT customerDepositBalanceID INTO customer_deposit_balance_id
    FROM CustomerDepositBalance
    WHERE customerID = customerID AND productID = NEW.productID;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO CustomerDepositBalance (customerID, productID, totalOrdered)
      VALUES (customerID, NEW.productID, NEW.quantity);
    ELSE
      UPDATE CustomerDepositBalance
      SET totalOrdered = totalOrdered + NEW.quantity
      WHERE customerDepositBalanceID = customer_deposit_balance_id;
    END IF;

  ELSIF TG_TABLE_NAME = 'DepositReturnDetails' THEN
    SELECT customerID INTO customerID FROM DepositReturns WHERE depositReturnID = NEW.depositReturnID;

    SELECT customerDepositBalanceID INTO customer_deposit_balance_id
    FROM CustomerDepositBalance
    WHERE customerID = customerID AND productID = NEW.productID;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO CustomerDepositBalance (customerID, productID, totalReturned)
      VALUES (customerID, NEW.productID, NEW.quantity);
    ELSE
      UPDATE CustomerDepositBalance
      SET totalReturned = totalReturned + NEW.quantity
      WHERE customerDepositBalanceID = customer_deposit_balance_id;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

If you have any other recommendations to approach this than using a trigger, I'd appreciate it as well.
Edit: I've added the inserts below. It's for the Customers, Inventories, Products, Orders, OrderDetails, DepositReturns, DepositReturnDetails table.
INSERT INTO Customers (
  customerBusinessName, 
  customerBusinessAddress, 
  customerBillingAddress, 
  customerVAT, 
  Location, 
  ContactName, 
  ContactNo, 
  ContactEmail
)
VALUES
  ('Dazai Osamu Book Store', 
  '123 Book Street, City, State 45678', 
  '456 Dazai Osamu Lane, City, State, 12345', 
  1234567890123,
  'Tokyo',
  'Dazai',
  '111-111-1111',
  'dazai@osamu.com'
  );


INSERT INTO Products (
  productName,
  productSKU,
  productSize,
  productType
)
VALUES
    ('ProductA', 'SKU001', 'Large', 'TypeA'),
    ('ProductB', 'SKU002', 'Large', 'TypeB');


INSERT INTO Facilities (
  facilityType, 
  facilityLocation, 
  facilityName
)
VALUES
  ('Warehouse', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo Warehouse');

INSERT INTO Inventories (
  productID,
  inventoryDate,
  facilityID,
  quantity
)
VALUES
    ((SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'), 
    NOW(),
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    5000),
    ((SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'), 
    NOW(),
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    5000);

INSERT INTO Orders(
  customerID,
  orderDate,
  orderDeliveryDate,
  orderDeliveryTimeEarliest,
  orderDeliveryTimeLatest,
  orderPaymentStatus,
  orderDeliveryStatus,
  orderNotes
)
VALUES
  (
    (SELECT customerID FROM Customers WHERE customerBusinessName = 'Dazai Osamu Book Store'),
    NOW() - INTERVAL '2 DAY',
    '2024-10-01',
    '14:00:00',
    '18:00:00',
    FALSE,
    FALSE,
    'No notes one'
  ),
  (
    (SELECT customerID FROM Customers WHERE customerBusinessName = 'Dazai Osamu Book Store'),
    NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY',
    '2024-10-01',
    '14:00:00',
    '18:00:00',
    FALSE,
    FALSE,
    'No notes twee'
  ),
  (
    (SELECT customerID FROM Customers WHERE customerBusinessName = 'Dazai Osamu Book Store'),
    NOW(),
    '2024-11-01',
    '14:00:00',
    '18:00:00',
    FALSE,
    FALSE,
    'Order tres :)'
  );

INSERT INTO OrderDetails(
  orderID,
  fromFacilityID,
  productID,
  quantity
)
VALUES
  (1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'),
    100),
  (1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'),
    100),
  (2,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'),
    500),
  (2,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'),
    500),
  (3,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'),
    300),
  (3,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'),
    300),

INSERT INTO DepositReturns (
  customerID,
  depositStatus,
  depositReturnPayment,
  depositReturnDate
)
VALUES
  (
    (SELECT customerID FROM Customers WHERE customerBusinessName = 'Dazai Osamu Book Store'),
    TRUE, 
    'Waived', 
    NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
  ),
  (
    (SELECT customerID FROM Customers WHERE customerBusinessName = 'Dazai Osamu Book Store'),
    TRUE, 
    'Paid',
    NOW()
  );

INSERT INTO DepositReturnDetails (
  depositReturnID,
  toFacilityID,
  productID,
  quantity
)
VALUES
    (
    1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'),
    100
  ),
  (
    1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'),
    100
  ),
    (
    1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU001'),
    50
  ),
  (
    1,
    (SELECT facilityID FROM Facilities WHERE facilityName = 'Tokyo Warehouse'),
    (SELECT productID FROM Products WHERE productSKU = 'SKU002'),
    50
  );



Please add some sample/mock data and a series of inserts that could let others reproduce the problem.

Just added them! @Zegarek
